# Docker Compose WP permissions

Tags: docker, wordpress, file-permissions, docker-compose, disk-volume

I've a docker compose creating a WP container.
The container has a more recent version of WP than the one I'm trying to import, so WP ask me to update the database and some folders.
The update process fail, complaining about some permissions on folder creation. How can I solve this?

```
wp-my-domain-com:
    image: wordpress:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: wp-my-domain-com
    volumes:
      - ./wp/my-domain-com/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: my_domain_com
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      VIRTUAL_HOST: www.mydomain.com,mydomain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: mydomain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: tech@mydomain.com
      TZ: Europe/Rome
    restart: always
```

Many thanks in advance.